# Understanding std::vector specification

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The draft for the c++14 standard n4140 [[vector.overview]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/vector.overview#1)  states the following:

> A vector is a sequence container that supports random access iterators. In addition, it supports (amortized) constant time insert and erase operations at the end; insert and erase in the middle take linear time. Storage management is handled automatically, though hints can be given to improve efficiency. The elements of a vector are stored contiguously, meaning that if `v` is a `vector<T, Allocator>` where `T` is some type other than `bool`, then it obeys the identity `&v[n] == &v[0] + n` for all `0 <= n < v.size()`.

Why is the identity `&v[n] == &v[0] + n` for all `0 <= n < v.size()` true for all types except bool? As far as my understanding goes, C++ is byte adressed. So this should only hold true for types, that are one byte in size.

Comment: What address would you get if you add `1` to `int* ptr`? `+1` or `+sizeof(int)`?

Comment: `vector<bool>` is a specialization that uses bit-packed representation, one bit per element. This is widely considered an unfortunate mistake, but we are probably stuck with it now, for backward compatibility. For details, see **[vector.bool]** section of the standard.

Comment: @Evg got it. If you add one to `int*` the value increases by sizeof(int). That is why this holds true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `vector<bool>` is not just a `vector` that holds `bool`s. It is an entirely different sort of beast. There is a [partial specialization](http://eel.is/c++draft/sequences#vector.bool) for it - and it behaves as a dynamic bitset, storing 8 `bool`s in one byte. So that identity does not hold. Indeed, you cannot even get a `bool&` out of a `vector<bool>`, you only get proxy references.

> So this should only hold true for types, **that are one byte in size**.

The size here doesn't matter. `&v[n] == &v[0] + n` holds for *all* types, *except* `bool`. For `bool`, this is ill-formed, because `&v[0]` isn't a valid expression at all (much less a pointer).

---

To word this in a different way. For all `T` except for `bool`, `vector<T>` behaves a lot like a `T[]` with dynamic, known length. `v[i]` is a specific `T`, `&v[i]` is a pointer to a specific `T`. Everything you know and love about arrays applies to `vector`. Like that pointer identity.

But `vector<bool>` is *not* a `bool[]`. `v[i]` is not a specific `bool`, it is an object that is convertible to `bool`. `&v[i]` is not a pointer to a specific `bool`, it is not even a valid expression because `v[i]` isn't an lvalue.

Things you try to do with `vector<T>` for unknown `T` that work with every other `T` fail with `bool`, like:

```
std::vector<T> v = ...;
for (auto& elem : v) { ... } // ok for every T. except bool.
```

Answer (score 4):

`&v[0]` is a pointer to the type enclosed by the vector (except for `vector<bool>`). `&v[0]`+ n changes the pointer to point to the n'th element regardless of how large the element is in bytes.

As Barry noted, a `vector<bool>' is a specialization to reduce the space consumed and pack bits. It's unlike all other`vector` containers. This become problematic when doing something like:

```
vector<bool> b{true, false};
auto& val=b[0];
```

val is not a reference to a bool!